# Context module not displaying block on panels' taxonomy page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, panels, 7

I am overriding a taxonomy term page with panels and I need context (module) to display a block for the taxonomy term. 
When I use the default taxonomy Page (no override), the context is active, but when I override it with Page manager the context isn't active and the block doesn't show up. 
I achieve the same setup with node types for og and it worked without an issue. 
Any help on what I am missing out with the taxonomy page setup?